# Disabled ZooKeeper in bootstrap.yml, it still runs during testing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-zookeeper

I am running a SpringBoot App. I have bootstrap-test.yml (located under src/test/resources/config), which looks like:

```
spring.cloud.config.enabled: false
spring.cloud.service-registry.auto-registration.enabled: false
spring.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.enabled: false
spring.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.register: false
```

pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zookeeper-discovery</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

However, when I try to run an integration test:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@DirtiesContext 
@SpringBootTest
public class TestClass......
```

ZooKeeper still attempts to connect "live":

```
16:02:14.752 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.memory.free=493MB
16:02:14.752 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.memory.max=8116MB
16:02:14.752 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.memory.total=610MB
16:02:14.778 [main] INFO  o.a.c.f.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Starting
16:02:14.783 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=60000 watcher=org.apache.curator.ConnectionState@76d828ff
16:02:14.788 [main] INFO  o.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket - jute.maxbuffer value is 4194304 Bytes
16:02:14.798 [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
16:02:14.805 [main] INFO  o.a.c.f.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Default schema
16:02:16.805 [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] WARN  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:357)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1214)
```

I want to disable all zookeeper bootstrap actions for integration test. What gives, I'm frustrated and have no idea what is wrong: why is Zookeeper still trying to run when I disabled it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work !

```
spring.cloud.zookeeper.enabled=false
```

for `yaml`,

```
spring:
  cloud:
    zookeeper:
        enabled: false
```

Comment: Tried it, yml uses ":" instead of "=". I made my bootstrap-test.yml hold only: spring.cloud.zookeeper.config.enabled: false. Zookeeper still runs.

Comment: @Alpha_Omega i think for `yaml`, you need to put in nested structure, not inline. (Each one nested by tab space)

Comment: It still doesn't work, this is really weird. Other answers on stackoverflow clearly stated this should be working. How do I find out if Spring is even picking up my bootstrap config?

Comment: holy crap you are a genius

Comment: hehe, Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you! I was struggling on this for literally 2 hours.